# R Excluir linhas do data frame por condição

Tags: r, data.frame, condição

Tenho o seguinte conjunto de dados:

```
Nome <- c("Laetia","Vouacapoua","Lecythis","Pourouma","Poraqueiba","Pseudopiptadenia", "Abarema");
I1 <- c(1,3,3,2,3,3,3);
I2 <- c(1,3,1,3,3,3,3);
I3 <- c(1,3,1,3,2,3,3);
I4 <- c(1,3,2,2,3,3,3)

x <- data.frame(Nome,I1,I2,I3,I4)
```

exemplo:

```
              Nome I1 I2 I3 I4
1           Laetia  1  1  1  1
2       Vouacapoua  3  3  3  3
3         Lecythis  3  1  1  2
4         Pourouma  2  3  3  2
5       Poraqueiba  3  3  2  3
6 Pseudopiptadenia  3  3  3  3
7          Abarema  3  3  3  3
```

Gostaria de excluir as linhas nas quais linhas aparece o caractere "3", porém somente aquelas que estão presentes em todas as colunas "I", gerando este resultado:

```
              Nome I1 I2 I3 I4
1           Laetia  1  1  1  1
3         Lecythis  3  1  1  2
4         Pourouma  2  3  3  2
5       Poraqueiba  3  3  2  3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode aplicar `any()` em cada linha para manter aquelas que tenham pelo menos uma célula diferente da condição:

```
x[apply(x[-1] != 3, 1, any),]

        Nome I1 I2 I3 I4
1     Laetia  1  1  1  1
3   Lecythis  3  1  1  2
4   Pourouma  2  3  3  2
5 Poraqueiba  3  3  2  3
```